# Why is my gridview rebound after selected index change?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview that is populated through SQLDataSource. The query behind is rather complex and the GridView takes some seconds to get filled; that's why I get annoyed by the fact that every time I select a row, the Gridview disappears for a while and is getting repopulated again. What does fire that rebind?

The selected row index works as Control Parameter for a second Gridview, that displays detail information on that row. There are these 2 events defined for the gridview:

```
protected void GridView_PURCHTABLE_OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) {
if(DisplayPurchItems.Checked == false)
{
  GridView_PURCHTABLE.Columns[4].Visible = false;
}
else
{
  GridView_PURCHTABLE.Columns[4].Visible = true;
}

protected void GridView_PURCHTABLE_Selectedindexchanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    GridView_Notes.DataBind();  //this is the second gridview
}
```

Anyone has a clue what might cause the gridview to rebind?
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Check once:Is post back.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            //binding grid
        }
        }
```

Comment: I placed the GridView_Notes.DataBind() in the condition and deleted it from the SelectedIndexChange event. Selecting a row then causes the second GridView to bind! Does that means that selecting a row causes a page reload? - As it is not a PostBack? But why?

Comment: I am not sure but yes,doing any action on the grid,cause the page to reload(Please validate once).@Barnabeck